# Exclude sources files for apt-get update

Tags: apt, aptitude

I use an specific command to check security updates:

```
/usr/bin/apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list
```

But when executed it use sources files in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/**. So i want this command **only** read the specified source file. How to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `Dir::Etc::SourceParts`:

```
apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list -o Dir::Etc::SourceParts=/some/valid/dir/false
```

You can use whatever instead of `false`, you can use a valid empty directory if you want.